# Multiple OR filters in django-nonrel are not allowed, workaround?

Tags: django, django-models, django-nonrel

I am using django-nonrel 1.3 with MongoDB 2.0.7 and facing this known issue-
Multiple OR statements are not allowed while filtering QuerySet.

https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine/issues/140

I don't see any progress on that one. Could you suggest any workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the model admin I have overridden the queryset function to clean up the query. Of course this only stops the 500 error, and throws away all but the first query string.

```
def clean_query(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        get_data = request.GET.copy()
        get_data['q'] = get_data['q'].split(" ")[0]
        request.GET = get_data

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        clean_query(request)
        return super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request)
```

I'm sure the same can be done for a normal model manager.